# I need an idea of how to get a unique random row from the databse

Tags: java, mysql, sql

At the moment i am returning a random row like this

```
SELECT id, title from ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

I need to return a random but unique row. so if the first time I get row id = 15 the next time I want row 15 taken out of the result pool so I'll never get row 15 again

I figured I could technically do something like this

```
SELECT id, title from where id <>15 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

but this statement will quickly grow to something like this

```
SELECT id, title from where id <> 15 AND id <> 16 AND id <> 20 AND id <> 25 AND id <> 5 AND id <> 6 AND id <> 18 AND id <> 19 AND id <> 100 AND id <> 105 AND id <> 195 AND id <> 155 AND   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

this growing is a bit of a problem because I need to keep track these seen ids by passing them to the webpage and back again to the server or might have to keep a session for each user containing all their seen IDs. All of this is a lot of extra work so first I want to know if there is any other way of doing this.

Is there another way that I don't know about for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: An `IN ()` clause, a `previous_values` table ? If there is a single user update a `lastreturned` column with a timestamp and exclude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intialize a string variable to "0"  Let's call that variable Session.IDsSeen.

Make your query look like this:

```
where id not in (Session.IDsSeen)
```

Each time you run the query, append a comma and the id to Session.IDsSeen.

Note that this answer shows the logic only.  You will want to use a query parameter for Sessionl.IDsSeen but since I'm not a java programmer, I don't know the java way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store a list of possible ID's for each user in the session.  When they first visit your site generate a list with all possible ID's. ArrayList or some kind of list would be fine.  Then each time you need a new id just generate a random number between 0 and (ArrayList.size() - 1).  Then do ArrayList.get(randomNumber) and do your select on that.  Then After the select just remove from ArrayList ArrayList.remove(randomNumber) and then repeat as needed.

If number of records is an issue (more than 2,147,483,647) then use LinkedList instead.

Example of query:

```
//retrieve arraylist from session.
//generate randomNumber between 0 and (ArrayList.size() - 1)
statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, title from table where id = \'" + ArrayList.get(randomNumber) + "\';");
ArrayList.remove(randomNumber);
//put updated ArrayList back in session.
```

Comment: This approach could have problems if the table has enough records.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Based on the user's question I am assuming it doesn't 2,147,483,647 and that is only for an arraylist.  He could use a linkedlist and not face this problem.  But you are correct I edited my post.